# Problem with import of images/ correct path of files

Tags: html, image, import

Hi there I have problem with import from local to host imgaes off site. 
The browser generates a 404 error ,even though the path in the code is correct
and locally everything works fine... 
Please help below  site adrees:
http://centrum.framat86.ayz.pl/index.html
and
http://centrum.framat86.ayz.pl/o_nas.html

the file name also has no errors

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Can you confirm there which _actual URL_ is requested and how it deviates from your expectations?

Comment: Yes i know that thats not problem beacuse images are imported on this way and the are in folder on host...http://centrum.framat86.ayz.pl/images/image10.jpg

Comment: I checked whether the file exists or not through the developer tools of the browser and it claims that the file does not exist. If the file path is truly correct, it may be a server side issue. I also tried accessing the /Images/ folder but encountered a 403 forbidden message.

Comment: ok, so I'll check another server or can it be the fault of the import program (fillezilla)?

Comment: I have the same problem on another host :/

Answer (score 0):

You might need to re-upload the image files that have the problem. Try to delete the image files first before reuploading. 
And make sure the image file can be opened before you upload it.

If that doesn't work, you can use external image hosting service such as imgur.com

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21988022)

Comment: Unfortunately, this procedure did not help, so what can be the reason? I think I will use this site about which you wrote

Comment: @PhilippKief what can I do, I dont have reputation, and my answer is not asking clarification. I just want to help, remember code of cunduct "build a kind, collaborative community". Reviewers make people lazy to help others!

Comment: @Mariusz maybe this is because of the limit in free hosting. Anyway, if my method works please vote my answer so I can have reputation.